# How can I pass a override to a struct template type or variable template type to a function?

Tags: c++

I'm not even sure what this is called.

I wish to do something like this...  Have a function that takes as an arg a reference to a template type with two templates, but one of them is not set in stone.

my question is what do I put in place of `WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE` to get this to compile?  I've tried various things like passing void and "struct Hash" (that 2nd template is declared as `class Hash = hash<Value>`)

Note:  I can't use c++11.

```
void doTest(std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string, WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE> &set) {
    ...
}

struct HashStructOne {
   size_t operator()(const std::string &item) const {...}
};

struct HashStructTwo {
   size_t operator()(const std::string &item) const {...}
};

int main() {
   std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string, HashStructOne>  set1;
   std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string, HashStructTwo>  set2;
   doTest(set1);
   doTest(set2);
}
```

Comment: `HashStructOne` and `HashStructTwo` are two distinct types.  I don't think there is any way to use the same function on two different types or member functions without using a template or virtual functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
template<typename PUT_SOMETHING_HERE>
void doTest(std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string, PUT_SOMETHING_HERE> &set) {
        ...
    }
```

The name of the template argument doesn't have to be anything specific, it just has to match the name in the template of the function argument where you want the type to be substituted.

Comment: That results in a compiler error when trying to call with a set based on:  HashStructOne:  error: no matching function for call to ‘doTest(std::tr1::unordered_set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, HashStructOne, std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, false> (&)())’

Comment: What version of compiler are you using? Just curious since you're still using the `tr1` namespace...

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)...  sadly I cannot go newer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution to

```
void doTest(std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string, WHAT_DO_I_PUT_HERE> &set) {
    ...
}
```

… is just

```
template< class Foo >
void doTest( std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string, Foo>& set )
{
    ...
}
```

---

I've found it useful to also pass the name of the type to the test function (for output), because the name from `typeid(T).name()` is not guaranteed readable, especially with g++.

Then I just define a macro like

```
#define DO_TEST( Type ) test<Type>( #Type )
```